# Why TRichEdit removes images from a loaded file when TRichEdit.ReadOnly?

Tags: delphi, vcl, trichedit

When I try to load an RTF file using `RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FilePath)` method and `RichEdit1.ReadOnly = True` then the RichEdit removes all images from the RTF file and shows an empty area in their place:

[image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BasePath: String;
  FilePath: String;
begin
  GetDir(0, BasePath);
  FilePath := BasePath + '\TestRtfFileMS.Rtf';

  RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile(FilePath);

  RichEdit2.ReadOnly := True;
  RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromFile(FilePath);
end;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me. You should report it on https://quality.embarcadero.com/login.jsp

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: If I create an RTF file with an image in WordPad, the image is always lost when I open the RTF document in the `TRichEdit` control. But if I create an "identical" document in Word 2010, the image is indeed shown in the `TRichEdit` control, but fails to load if `ReadOnly = True`, as discovered by the OP. Remy's question is also very relevant, since the `TRichEdit` was rather heavily updated in Delphi 11.

Comment: (joking) Pictures are not text, so `.ReadOnly` has to be taken literally and works as intended: just text remains.

Comment: I tested in RAD Studio 11 Version 28.0.44500.8973

Comment: @DmitryB Just to check - do you have `RichEdit1.PlainText` set to `True` or `False`? It must be `False` to load RTF content.

Comment: Same behavior on DevExpress version of RichEdit. Can be depend on some policy? Wordpad asterisk me during opening - if check "unblock" picture is visible. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows.

1. First, write the *.rtf file containing the image in the "Word". (It should Not be written in the "Wordpad".)
2. At runtime, the rtf file is imported into TRichEdit and set to ReadOnly = True. (Not desigetime)

.

```
RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromFile('myFile.rtf');
RichEdit1.ReadOnly := True;
```